# JQuery on event in meteor template

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, meteor-blaze

How to achive `on` event in meteor template.

Ordinary Jquery code

```
$('.js-star-rating').on('change','input', function() {
  //Some codes
});
```

Meteor Template

```
Template.myTemplate.events({
// How to achieve above js code here
});
```

Comment: did you tried something like ```"change .js-star-rating input": function(e){}```?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/eventmaps

```
"change .js-star-rating input": function(event, tpl){}
```